# How to construct a named list (a SEXP) to be returned from the C function called with .Call()?

Tags: c, r, s-expression

I call C code via `.Call("foo", <args>)`, where foo calls other C
functions, computes the result and returns it. The result is a list
of length 3 and I would like to name this list. To this end, foo
does this:

```
/* Construct result list from variables containing the results */
SEXP res = PROTECT(allocVector(VECSXP, 3)); /* list of length 3 */
SET_VECTOR_ELT(res, 0, ScalarReal(a)); /* numeric(1) */ 
SET_VECTOR_ELT(res, 1, somenumericvector); /* numeric(<some length>) */
SET_VECTOR_ELT(res, 2, ScalarInteger(i)); /* integer(1) */

/* Name components and return */
SEXP nms = PROTECT(allocVector(STRSXP, 3)); /* names as SEXP */
char *nms_ = CHAR(STRING_ELT(nms, 0)); /* pointer to names */
char *names[3] = {"result_numeric", "result_numeric_vector", "result_integer"};
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) nms_[i] = names[i]; 
setAttrib(res, R_NamesSymbol, nms);
UNPROTECT(1); 
return res;
```

Is this a/the correct way of constructing a named list of length 3?

The C function indeed returns back to R but once I assign the output to a
variable in R, I immediately get a segmentation fault. What might be wrong? I
can put 'debug statement's' (simple `printf("...\n")` right before the above 'return
res;' and they are executed fine.
Is there any convenient way to debug C code called from R?

Comment: FWIW this would be much easier with the `Rcpp` API.

Comment: And that is even easier if you set the names from R.

Comment: I know, but I'm interested in the 'plain' way.

Comment: See here: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/C-interface.html section "Character vectors and lists" to see how to build a `character` object from C. I guess you should replace `nms_[i] = names[i]` with `SET_STRING_ELT(nms, i, mkChar(names[i]));`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An alternative to BrodieG's answer is to use `mkNamed` from Rinlinedfuns.h (which contains an example of how to use `mkNamed`).

```
/* Construct named result list from variables containing the results */
const char *names[] = {"result_numeric", "result_numeric_vector",
    "result_integer", ""};                   /* note the null string */
SEXP res = PROTECT(mkNamed(VECSXP, names));  /* list of length 3 */
SET_VECTOR_ELT(res, 0, ScalarReal(a));       /* numeric(1) */ 
SET_VECTOR_ELT(res, 1, somenumericvector);   /* numeric(<some length>) */
SET_VECTOR_ELT(res, 2, ScalarInteger(i));    /* integer(1) */
UNPROTECT(1);
return res;
```

Answer (score 5):

Since you ask for the plain vanilla way, you need to create an R character vector from the C strings using `mkChar` and `SET_STRING_ELT`:

```
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) SET_STRING_ELT(nms, i, mkChar(names[i]));
```

Right now, you are trying to use the raw C string as an R object, which won't work.

Re:debugging, you can use **[`PrintValue`](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-exts.html#Inspecting-R-objects)** in C code to print out R objects.

All this said, unless you have a very specific reason for wanting plain vanilla, you should consider `Rcpp`.

Comment: This is not exactly what I said in the comments?

Comment: @nicola, yes, this is similar, though more complete.  Moreover, from memory on first read you only provided a link, not the SET_STRING_ELT stuff.  Did you edit or am I miss-remembering?

Comment: And to be clear, I did not copy paste your stuff.  It just so happens that by using the OPs variable names we ended up with exactly the same thing.

Comment: Yes, I edited and don't worry about that. Just seemed strange to see an answer with the same exact line without a citation. Anyway +1 especially for the `PrintValue` part.

Answer (score 3):

Per @nrussell's good advice, a solution in a single statement (broken over four lines for legibility)

```
R> cppFunction('List marius(double a, NumericVector b, int c) \
       { return List::create(Named("resnum")=a,\ 
                             Named("resvec")=b, \
                             Named("resint")=c); }')
R> marius(1.2, sqrt(3:5), 42L)
$resnum
[1] 1.2

$resvec
[1] 1.73205 2.00000 2.23607

$resint
[1] 42

R>
```